# New tab open when clicking the Send button

Tags: facebook, firefox, facebook-like

I notice this behaivior today, now using Firefox (have not tried other browsers) when I click the send button that is displayed with the Like button, it opens a new tab with the social plugin on it.

I tested it here and the issue was happening: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a Facebook bug - see more at

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/177102442412197